# What is id= name= .something #something?

Tags: html, css

In HTML are the attributes like

```
<input class="new" type="text" name="title" id="title2" />
```

and in CSS do I see

```
.something { ... }
#something { ... }
```

What is `id=` `name=` `.something` `#something` used for?

Comment: Funny you should know jQuery and server-side web dev, but not know these attributes and selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- ID: unique identifier for the DOM element
- Name: name to be used when submitting a form which is used as the data retrieval key
- `#something`: reference to element with ID 'something'
- `.something`: reference to element(s) with classname 'something'

These are some *really* basic concepts of HTML and CSS. You will probably want to read a [basic HTML tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/) to find out more on the subject, especially the [attributes section](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp).

**Id's and classnames are primary used for styling elements with CSS and adding behaviour to them with JavaScript. *For example:***

**HTML:**

```
<button id="foo">Click me to unleash the Unicorn</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
#foo { 
    border: 1px solid #ff0000; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    background: #000; 
    color: #fff; 
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'http://display.ubercomments.com/6/23672.jpg';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(img);
};
```

[See also, this beautiful example (Unicorn included).](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/k6c7M/)

Answer (score 2):

An `id` attribute is a unique identifier for the element within the DOM. It's unique in the sense that you cannot have more than one element with this ID contained within the document.

Styling an element based on ID is done using `#something`.

A `name` attribute is simply a non-unique name for this element. This is most commonly used  in forms as the name that gets `POST`'d or `GET`'d through to the server side language.

`.something` is the style selector for the `class=` attribute on any element.

For instance, you could style the following element: `<div class="testclass" name="testname" id="testid"></div>` in any of the following 3 ways:

```
.testclass {
    background-color: black;
}

#testid {
    background-color: black;
}

div[name="testname"] {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Remember, both a class and a name are **NOT** unique, so they can be used to style and define multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

The **.something** is a class, and the **#something** is an id. 
the Name= attribute is commonly used in forms, and usually not used in CSS.
In other words, the following code:

```
<body class="thisisaclass">
<div id='thisisanid'></div>
<div class='thisisanotherclass'></div>
</body>
```

Would result in a CSS that looks like this:

```
.thisisaclass {..Code..}
.thisisaclass #thisisanid {..Code..}
.thisisanotherclass {...code...}
```

Classes are used for repeating stuff, for example if you want to use the same type of text formatting in several areas of your page - whereas ids only should appear once in the html code.

Check out [HTMLDog](http://htmldog.com/guides/) to learn more, it's a great start :)

Comment: @GlitchMr whilst the tutorials isn't _that_ advanced, like I said its a good place to start. Obviously any good programmer should combine and read more than one source to learn. I wasn't aware w3schools was **that** bad though >_>

Answer (score 0):

- `id="something"` means ID. You can have it only once. It's CSS reference is `#something`. Also, by using `#something` at end of address, you can directly move browsers to that ID, without using JS.
- `name=` is used while sending form. Using PHP, you can check that value by using `$_REQUEST['title']`. In other programming languages, there also are methods to get that value.
- `.something` is class in CSS. It's used to style HTML elements with `class="something"`

Answer (score 0):

class is multiple selector for example if you want many tables have same colors, back ground colors and font etc. You will define class.
In these tables if a specific table is to style in different way you will use id. Id can not be duplicated. And you can assign a same class to as many objects you want.

```
<style type="text/css">
.MyTable{
background-color:#ff00ff;
}
#centralTable{
background:color:red;
}
</style>

<div class="MyTable">Data </div>
<div class="MyTable"> </div>
<div class="MyTable" id ="centralTable"> Data</div>
<div class="MyTable"> Data</div>
<div class="MyTable">Data </div>
```

**Remember classes are followed by period (`.`) and Ids (`#`) in Cascading Style Sheets.**